# In functional languages, how is the concept of immutability applied to addresses in memory?

Tags: pointers, functional-programming, immutability

I'm trying to understand how a lot of basic computer science concepts are implemented in functional languages. The point that I can't currently understand is how functional languages and philosophies deal with addresses in memory.

In the context of a very base computer science concept like sorts, how are issues of immutability dealt with efficiently? I know that structural sharing is really needed to keep memory from blowing up. But in my mind this means that relatively simple concepts like selection sort can become quite complicated.

Can someone explain how a functional language deals with in place sorts? Is the idea of being "in place" thrown out and replaced with a data structure that supports structural sharing?

I'm really trying to understand how immutability fits with addresses in memory (think pointers). For example, in an in place sort data is not destroyed, but it is moved to new addresses. Is this considered mutation? I think the answer is yes. But then how can you do things like rotations to balance a binary tree? How do functional programmers think about pointers?

I know that this is relatively hard question to answer, but I feel like its a big issue with respect to really understanding the functional paradigm. Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is probably more suitable for [computerscience.se] rather than here. This site is for specific programming (code) or programmers tools related questions. Your question is pretty broad.

Answer (score 4):

1. Just to get this out of the way:

   > For example, in an in place sort data is not destroyed, but it is moved to new addresses.

   This does not make any sense. If the data is "moved to new addresses", the algorithm, by definition, no longer works "in place".
2. There is a long tradition of functional programming languages that do not insist on 100% purity. Starting with Lisp, over ML, then OCaml, Scala or Clojure - all these languages have mutable data structures. In "multi-paradigm" languages that have aspects of functional programming, like JavaScript and Python and even Java, you also have mutable data structures. Haskell is rather an exception in its insistence on purity.
3. Most functional programming languages *prefer* persistent data structures and algorithms that work on immutable data structures. That is, instead of a mutable hash map, those languages would usually prefer some kind of balanced sorted tree, and instead of mutable list buffers, they would prefer immutable singly-linked lists. For sorting those lists, you could take merge-sort, which is nicely expressible as a pure functional program (but is not in-place, at least not without some considerable extra effort).
4. Even if you insist on purity, you can still treat the mutable memory of your computer just like yet another part of the mutable "outside world" - as if it were some kind of user input-output, system clock, network communication, or a random number generator. That is, to deal with mutable memory in a pure functional way, you would need two components: first, you would need a way to describe *what is to be done with the mutable memory* by constructing a "plan" - which is immutable; and then, you would need an interpreter that can take this immutable plan, and apply it to an actual mutable chunk of memory. That is, the interpreter that mutates memory becomes somewhat external to the core of the language, and is treated just like any other part of the "external mutable world".
5. In languages which do not insist on purity, you can implement *both* the little domain-specific language for constructing the immutable plans, as well as the interpreter that actually mutates the memory, thereby separating the pure parts from the impure side-effecty mutable parts. For example, Chiusano & Bjarnason in their book "Functional Programming in Scala" have a chapter 14.2.5 *literally* called *"A purely functional in-place quicksort"*.
6. In general, in statically typed functional programming, immutability is not the goal in itself. The goal is rather to ensure that half-backed mutable data structures do not escape the narrow scope of the algorithm for which the mutability is advantageous. If you find a way to ensure that, then it means that you can write purely functional programs that make use of mutable memory.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion comes from promiscuously mixing levels of abstraction.

How is memory allocation handled in your favorite OO garbage-collected language (Python, Java, Ruby, etc)? You don't know. That detail is left to the compiler and/or runtime. You are confusing the *semantics of a programming language* with an *implementation detail* for a compiler of that language. I will grant that C/C++ blur the distinction considerably, but that blurring is probably the most salient feature of those languages at this point.

Consider a common associative data structure, the C struct:

```c
struct address 
{ 
    char number[10]; 
    char street[100]; 
    char city[50]; 
    char state[15]; 
};
```

We know, in advance, what this will look like in memory. But consider a similar data structure in, say, Java:

```java
public class Record {
    public int number;
    public String street;
    public String city;
    public String state;
}
```

How's that going to layout in memory? You don't know. Even if you replace the Strings with character buffers, you don't *really* know. Obviously javac makes it happen. It's no different with persistent data structures in functional languages: where stuff gets put in memory is up to the *compiler*, which is not bound by the semantics of the language it's compiling.